# How do I add animated text on these images when I hover my cursor without changing current style?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, css-transitions

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery h2 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery h2:before,
.gallery h2:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to var(--direction, left), var(--yellow), transparent);
}

.gallery h2:after {
  --direction: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <h2>Instant Grams</h2>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/201x201" alt="">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/202x202" alt="">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/203x203" alt="">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/204x204" alt="">
</section>
```

I would like to show hello message to user when he hovers on any of these images. I tried online solutions but it changes my component style. I would like to keep my current styles same as I am using Grid layout, and I want to add animated text when user hovers on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the color transparent and when hovering with color. Here is an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  color: transparent;
  transition: all 1s;
}

p:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #00d5ff;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hover below</h3>

<p>Hello</p>
```

You can also do it with images! To do this, you need to position the text over the image, making it transparent. Then you have to give it a color with a hover effect. For a nicer effect you can make the image darker when hovering over it.

Here's another example:

```css
/* Gallery */

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.gallery h2 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
.gallery h2:before,
.gallery h2:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to var(--direction, left), var(--yellow), transparent);
}

.gallery h2:after {
  --direction: right;
}

/* Image Boxes */

.gallery-item {
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
  transition: all .5s;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-item:hover {
  color: #fff;
  filter: brightness(90%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">

<h2>Instant Grams</h2>

<div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="">
  <div class="text">Some text...</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/201x201" alt="">
  <div class="text">Some text...</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/202x202" alt="">
  <div class="text">Some text...</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-item">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/203x203" alt="">
  <div class="text">Some text...</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery h2 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery h2:before,
.gallery h2:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to var(--direction, left), var(--yellow), transparent);
}

.gallery h2:after {
  --direction: right;
}
.gallery-item {
  position: relative;
}
.gallery-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.greeting {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.gallery-item:hover .greeting {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <h2>Instant Grams</h2>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/201x201" alt="">
    <div class="greeting">Hello 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/202x202" alt="">
    <div class="greeting">Hello 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/203x203" alt="">
    <div class="greeting">Hello 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/204x204" alt="">
    <div class="greeting">Hello 4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```