# Hover Effect "change your picture" with icon on profile picture

Tags: html, css, styles

I would like to get a hover effect on my image, when the user goes over the image a background should appear on the image with some text (see example below). My css doesn't look like it at all unfortunately. It is not in the middle and the image is not round but more like an egg.

My question now is, how can I use CSS to make the image so that it is round and when going over it the text is displayed nicely in the middle.

I also use Bootstrap as an additional library, if it should be easier.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

*Pic.js*

```
<div class="container-profilepic">
     <img src="./image.png" width="150" height="150" alt="Profibild" className="photo-preview"></img>
     <div class="middle-profilepic">
            <div class="text-profilepic"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <div class="text-profilepic">Change it
     </div>
</div>
```

*Photo.css*

```
    .photo-preview{
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 125px !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    max-height: 125px!important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
  }

  .middle-profilepic {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .container-profilepic:hover .photo-preview {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  
  .container-profilepic:hover .middle-profilepic {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .text-profilepic {
    color: green;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

---

I checked this question befor out [How do I add animated text on these images when I hover my cursor without changing current style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66599568/how-do-i-add-animated-text-on-these-images-when-i-hover-my-cursor-without-changi)
Unfortunately it didn't help me.

I tried it before with `top`, `left`, `postion`...

```
  .middle-profilepic {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

The result

[image]

So I removed it, because the result was much closer at what I want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add animated text on these images when I hover my cursor without changing current style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66599568/how-do-i-add-animated-text-on-these-images-when-i-hover-my-cursor-without-changi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution

You need to set the parent `div` with `position: relative` and the inner content (icon + image) as `position: absolute` elements, stretching to fit.

If you need the avatar image to ba an `img` tag you can use `object-fit: cover` in CSS (It has wide support nowadays: https://caniuse.com/?search=object-fit).

#### Tips

- be careful the HTML you posted is invalid, has some broken tags
- I vividly suggest you move away from using heavily `!important` within your CSS

#### Working example

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.profilepic {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111;
}

.profilepic:hover .profilepic__content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.profilepic:hover .profilepic__image {
  opacity: .5;
}

.profilepic__image {
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.profilepic__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.profilepic__icon {
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.fas {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.profilepic__text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/solid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/svg-with-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="profilepic">
  <img class="profilepic__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510227272981-87123e259b17?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&fit=crop&h=200&w=200&s=3759e09a5b9fbe53088b23c615b6312e" width="150" height="150" alt="Profibild" />
  <div class="profilepic__content">
    <span class="profilepic__icon"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></span>
    <span class="profilepic__text">Edit Profile</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

1. Create a container with `relative` position and fixed `height` and `width`
2. Add an image as a background image respective to the container size
3. Add content with `position: absolute`

**solution using bootstrap-5**

```css
        .container-profilepic {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .photo-preview {
            background-image: url( https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531427186611-ecfd6d936c79?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80 );
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
        .middle-profilepic {
            background-color: rgba( 255,255,255, 0.69 );
        }
        .container-profilepic:hover .middle-profilepic {
            display: flex!important;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-profilepic card rounded-circle overflow-hidden">
        <div class="photo-preview card-img w-100 h-100"></div>
        <div class="middle-profilepic text-center card-img-overlay d-none flex-column justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-profilepic text-success">
                <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
                <div class="text-profilepic">Change it</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.image {
position: relative:
}
.text-div {
position: abolute;
top: 10px;
left:40%;
}
```

Also img tag it's self-closing tag